# bash fails to parse quoted string output from backtic expression

Tags: string, bash

why doesn't this work on a bash command line:

```
cat `echo "'filename with spaces'"`
```

It produces these errors:

```
cat: 'filename: No such file or directory
cat: with: No such file or directory
cat: spaces': No such file or directory
```

in other words, the single quotes in the string output by the command in the back-ticks is not parsed in the normal way. Does anyone know a way I can make this work? Or perhaps a better approach?

I've used `cat` and `echo` here as a simple example, but this behavior is rather annoying if, for example, you wish to process a list of files whose names are stored in a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `set -x` will be instructive.

What you would need is

```
cat "$(echo filename with spaces)"
```

But if what you're doing is reading newline-delimited file names from a file you should use a `while` `read` construct, like this:

```
while read -r file ; do cat "$file" ; done < file-names.txt
```

If you don't want to process each file but instead want to treat them all at once, use

```
IFS=$'\n' read -d '' -r -a files < file-names.txt
cat "${files[@]}"
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the quotation marks outside the `echo` command :

```
cat "`echo "filename with space"`"
```

or

```
cat "`echo filename\ with\ space`"
```

Answer (score 1):

This works at my side:

```
pearl.235> cat "my ine"
djkwnd
pearl.236> echo "my\ ine" | xargs cat
djkwnd
pearl.@].237>
```

Answer (score 1):

To get at what you're really trying to do, *"process a list of files whose names are stored in a file"*, there's no need for `cat`:

```
while IFS= read -r -d '' -u 9 filename
do
    echo "$filename"
done 9< "filename with spaces"
```

This enables you to process *any* paths, by assuming that `filename with spaces` contains NUL-separated paths. If you can take the risk of not being able to process filenames with newlines, simply remove `-d ''` from the above.

See [Useless Use of Cat](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html#uuk9letter) and especially the [Bash FAQ](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) for excellent information.

Answer (score 0):

```
cat "`echo filename with spaces`"
```

should work.

Other examples:

```
F='filename with spaces'

echo $F

filename with spaces

cat "${F}"
```

should work.